# Скрапинг разработчик python или php?

Tags: php, python, парсер, web-scraping

Какой язык лучше учить, чтобы в дальнейшем устроиться скрапинг разработчиком, php или python, с php знаком довольно давно и сейчас задаюсь вопросом, для карьерного роста в скрапинге стоит ли перейти на изучение python или возможно совсем другой язык для этого учить?
Знаю, только, что для серьезных скраперов нужны нереляционные базы, а какой к ним язык применять так и не определился?

Comment: Изучайте то что вам интереснее, а не под конкретную область. Сегодня вам нужен ваш скрайпинг - завтра нет, а язык как-бы уже не поменяете. Вашу задачу можно решить любым способом, 2 языка вполне развиты и имеют свою аудиторию, свои плюсы и минусы. Хоть я сам прогаю на `php`, но `python` - более универсальный, пыха - заточена под конкретную область, поэтому если вы не видите себя полностью в веб-разработке, то ответ очевиден.

Comment: Вопрос не по теме, задайте его на тостере что ли

Comment: А почему именно эти 2 языка ? Существует еще масса других языков, на которых так же удобно (а на некоторых очень удобно) делать скрапинг. И главное, вы уверены, что хотите всю жизнь сидеть и парсить сайты ? Очень часто начиная делать что то одно тут же находится десяток других задач, лежащих очень далеко от первоначальной. А работодатели ценят универсалов, которые способны решать любые задачи

Comment: @Mike всю жизнь не планирую парсингом заниматься, хочется очень так же заниматься в сферах близкими к сложным парсерам, такие как анализ данных, улучшать выдачу реклам, собирать и анализировать данные о пользователях

Comment: @Mike если знаете какой язык лучше учить, то поделитесь пожалуйста, сложность языка и время на обучение не пугает, готов взяться за любой язык который вы посоветуете для этих целей

Comment: @skeet.cc Никто вам не скажет, что лучше учить. У каждого свое мнение. Так что почему бы ни питон, раз php уже знаете. По крайней мере действительно распространенный _в данный момент_ универсальный язык. А то ведь я бы сказал, что удобный тут perl, потому как изначально планировался как язык обработки текстов. Только ведь в России его мало где используют. Большинство людей вообще считают его мертвым (не заслуженно). На самом деле в этом деле чем больше, тем лучше. В иные дни приходится понемногу на 3-5 языках что то делать :)

Comment: И да, работая с web без javascript точно не обойдетесь. И даже при парсинге. Данные они же не всегда на странице лежат. Может понадобится изучить работу api сайта и сделать свою реализацию работы с ним

Comment: Берите питон. Он более универсален, и с нереляционными базами хорошо дружит. Если изучите его, то потом ещё много куда можно будет развиваться.

Comment: @ я уже подобрал фреймворк для скрапинга, в целом мне можно начать изучать сразу его, если опыт в программировании есть или сам язык в начале изучить чуть-чуть?

Comment: @ если я хочу улучшать запросы в браузерах, выдачу рекламы и все, что связанно с анализом данных и скрапингом информации, то это data science называется или это не то направление?